# Permanently delete a path entry from my PATH inside virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, path, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have come across a lot of answers on how to add a path to PATH in virtualenv but none on how to remove one. I am working inside a virtualenv and the following code snippet:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

prints:

```
['',
 '/home/prk/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python27.zip', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
 '/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', 
 '/home/prk/.ipython']
```

Now I want to permanently remove `'/home/prk/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` from this list. Actually the problem is that I am importing a certain package (say a particular package **X**) in my python code. Now this package **X** is inside both my `Enthought` path (*first path in the list above*) and inside `anaconda2` (*second path onwards in the list above*). Now when I am importing **X**, I want it to access the **X** inside the `anaconda` path but since it searches for the imported packages sequentially through the list above it finds it in `Enthought` first and tries executing code in that. There are 3 ways that I can think of to solve this problem:

1. *Permanently remove `'/home/prk/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` from this list.* I thought I will edit the virtualenv's initialization files to remove or reorder the `PATH` to something more to my liking but I have no idea how to this. A temporary fix that works is:

   ```
   import sys
   del sys.path[1]
   import X
   ```

   But putting that inside every `.py` file inside my virtualenv is not possible.
2. Another way is to somehow add the `anaconda` paths before the `Enthought` path. I read about `.pth files`. I put a file with a `.pth` extension in my virtualenv's site-packages folder (`/home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`), with the absolute path to the directory containing my package as its only content. This doesn't work. I read in one of the comments [here](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/02/06/using-pth-files-for-python-development/) that it doesn't work on linux.
3. I thought I will delete and reinstall my virtualenv resetting it from scratch using all the paths but the one I don't want but I don't know why it always adds the `Enthought` path by default to the top of my list. Since I am working in a virtualenv shouldn't the list contain only paths inside my virtualenv (inside dato-env) as all other paths are except the first one?

**Edit 1** Inside my virtualenv:
`$PATH` displays:

```
bash: /home/prk/anaconda2/envs/dato-env/bin:
/home/prk/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

`$PYTHONPATH` and `$PYTHONHOME` display nothing.

Comment: What's the value of the env var `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` insdie the virtual env? What happens when you run python with  `-s` (Don't add user site dir to `sys.path`)

Comment: What version of `virtualenv` are you using?

Comment: @MartinKonecny Check edit. How to go about that second part of your question? After activating my dato-env (*source activate dato-env*) I am opening an ipython notebook and working on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your 'activate' bash file of your virtual environment to removes the directory you want. For this basically follow the steps below:

1. Open the 'activate' file in a text editor. you can find it at

   ```
   ../your_virtual_environment_folder/bin/activate
   ```
2. Add the below lines at the end of that file.

   ```
   directory_to_remove=/home/prk/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
   PATH=:$PATH:
   PATH=${PATH//:$directory_to_remove:/:}
   PATH=${PATH#:}; PATH=${PATH%:}`
   ```
3. Restart/reactivate your virtual environment.